# Beautifullsoup Attribute Error

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, attributeerror

Stupid problem...

```
for page in range(xxx, yyy):
url =  "%s%d" % (program_url, page)
opener = urllib2.build_opener() 
response = opener.open(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response)

print soup.find("strong").text
```

Sometimes the page don't contain any strong balise, so I have:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

How to avoid it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your print statement to:

```
if soup.find("strong"):
    print soup.find("strong").text
```

Answer (score 1):

You can test for a `None` object with the [`is not`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#is-not) operator:

```
result = soup.find("strong")
if result is not None:
    print result.text
```

Or, you can use a [`try/except`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#try) block to catch the error:

```
try:
    print soup.find("strong").text
except AttributeError:
    pass  # You should probably handle the error instead of use pass
```